# Is there a way to prevent a Shape for being transformed?

Tags: vuejs3, konvajs

That is the thing, i'm creating a shape that covers all canvas to act like a white background, i have a transformer and im listening to canvas clicks, inside it im adding objects into transformer nodes, but i don't like to transform the white shape that im using  as a background.

[Canvas white Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVgHy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't add transformer into it. I see several solutions:

1. Set `listening = false` on that background shape. In that case, it will not trigger any mouse/touch/pointer events
2. Or set a special name for it in just ignore in `click` callback

```js
const background = new Konva.Rect({
  fill: 'white',
  width: stage.width(),
  height: stage.height(),
  name: 'nonSelectable'
});



stage.on('click', (e) => {
  // ignore such shape
  if (e.target.hasName('nonSelectable')) {
    return;
  }
  // else attach transformer
});
```